# Prepare computer for presentation

Tags: laptop, desktop-customization

I need to use my laptop for a software presentation. I'd like to have nothing on the desktop but the link to the software. 
How to hide all the other stuff (Like the trash and bluetooth icons) and the smaller icons in the system tray?

Is there a tool to hide them temporary?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 3):

Making a separate user account will take care of any custom stuff you have in your profile -- desktop shortcuts, documents, etc. From there you can hide systray icons by either closing the programs or hiding the icons. Customizing exactly which icons are shown is a Windows Vista or later feature.

Answer (score 2):

Taking what allquixotic said a step further, in most operating systems there is a guest account. Just use that, and nothing that is "personal" will be there. Just the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Win 7. Did you try [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3659-desktop-icons-hide-show.html)?

As for hiding the icons click on the small triangle at the left of all the system icons. Then drag the icon into the box that ops-up.